# How to ignore .toJSON function when using JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, default, overriding, stringify

I found out that if you define [`.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) function for an object, then it's used to stringify an object, rather than default.
Is there a way to ignore this overridden function and run the default stringify process?

Comment: I suppose if you really wanted to override toJSON but still wanted to run the default stringify, you could iterate over they object and print the keys? You would be pretty much implementing stringify on your own though

Comment: The issue is - I use a 3rd party library from Parse.com service that works with its objects. Now I need to get an original representation of an object that is uses so that to pass it as a mock object to my unit tests. But that library defines its .toJSON() function which I want to ignore for test purpose.

Comment: If it's for debugging purposes, can you use console.log(obj)?

Comment: Yes, I can see it as a tree in Chrome console, but I can't copy and paste it as a string. I tried this trick http://superuser.com/questions/777213/copy-json-from-console-log-in-developer-tool-to-clipboard, but it seems to handle it with the same approach, so I get the result that is processed with .toJSON()

Comment: Ugly hack: `obj.toJSON = undefined`

Comment: Robert, please put it as an answer, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine the `toJSON` method in the specified object. For example:

```js
    function kryptonite(key)
       {
       var replacement = {};
       for(var __ in this)
         {
         if(__ in alias)
           replacement[__] = this[__]
         }
    
       return replacement;
       }
    
    var foo, bar;
    var alias = {"Clark":"","phone":""};
    var contact = {
                   "Clark":"Kent",
                   "Kal El":"Superman",
                   "phone":"555-7777"
                  }
    
    contact.toJSON = kryptonite;

    foo = JSON.stringify(contact);

    contact.toJSON = undefined;
    
    bar = JSON.stringify(contact);

    console.log("foo: ", foo);
    console.log("bar: ", bar);
```

**References**

- [JSON.stringify(): toJSON behavior - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior)
- [Versioning Language Features in JScript – JScript Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jscript/2009/04/16/versioning-language-features-in-jscript/)